# Are Harivamsa Purana lines 1.40.48-56 authentic?

Tags: harivamsa

Harivamsa Purana 1.40.48-56

> The distillate of various foods, rasa, vital-juice, produces blood, and flesh is produced from that blood.

Please tell me if this part is authentic

Comment: What do you mean by 'authentic'?

Comment: i meant to ask if that part of Harivamsa Purana is part of our scriptures because it is scientifically inaccurate and i didn't find any other translation because it is hard to find different translations for puranas.
i've heard that many of puranas we have today are not authentic